# Use of we ... yourself

Tags: programming

I use google translator to write english text. I write the text in english and let it translate into my mother tongue. So I can see "live" if the things I write can at least be understood by google translator.

I wrote the sentence below with "ourself" instead of "yourself". So google translator suggested "yourself" instead of "ourself". Therefore I thought that google translator knows some colloquial language in respect to this case. (This already happened to me.)

According to google-translator this sentence is correct:

> Yes, we build this "memorystream" yourself because we want to violate any good design rule.

However I'm no native speaker and "yourself" sounds a little weired to me in respect of the word "ourself".

The reason why I think that google translator might be right is, because in my dictionary "yourself" may also mean "self". This makes me guess that google may be right like in do-it-yourself or in respect to the patronizing "we", the Author's "we" or something like that.

**My question is: Is it valid to write "yourself" here?**

I try to explain that data will be assembled without using methods given by the framework. I wrote this in a sarcastic manner because this is usually considered a "bad design".

Comment: Thanks, now I understand better. I don't know of anything that would justify using "yourself" instead of "ourselves" here; I think it is just a bizarre suggestion from Google Translate. It might have been confused because the word "ourself", without a plural suffix, is in present-day English uncommon and considered nonstandard (it used to be used, but the standard first-person plural reflexive pronoun today is "oursel**ves**"). So it may have taken "ourself" to be a typo for "yourself", as they differ by only one letter

Comment: The reason why I think that google translator might be right is, because in my dictionary "yourself" may also mean "self". This makes me guess that google may be right like in do-it-yourself.

Comment: Just curious, do you or do you not want to violate good design rules?

Comment: Good design rules are good design rules because they fit in most situations. Sometimes you have to violate them to reach (mostly performance issued) goals. So here I want to violate the rule "when it's in the framework, use it" because using `MemoryStream` would lead to additional copy-tasks which degrade overall performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is wrong.

"Ourself" is not a real word. Google translate thinks that you forgot to put a "Y" in front. What you're trying to say is "We will build this ... ourselves".

Notice how we put "will" in the sentence. This is because you are saying that it will happen in the future, not that it is happening now. Also, ourself is not correct, because "we" is many people, and is plural. Anything ending with "-lf" turns into "-lves" when plural. Therefore, "ourselves"

By the way, good luck learning English.

Comment: [Ourself](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ourself) is most certainly a word, just not common or widely accepted.

Comment: @Skooba my autocorrect was driving me crazy insisting that its not a word, so its easier to just pretend it doesn't exist

Comment: *Ourself* is definitely a word. But maybe we should just each keep our opinion about that to ourself.

Answer (score -1):

*Drunk as I am; I'm gona* '***hik***' *update my anwserto... more BETTAR!!*

If you are trying to say, that we comply; consider:

*"**The architecture of the Memory System we built; implements the foundation of good software design**"*.

If you are trying to say, that we had to violate; consider:

*"**The Memory System we built violates conventional principles of good Software design, inorder to attain the performance characteristics that the system requires**"*.

Additional Considerations

**This is Spartan; this is Sarcasm!**

> *"**No! We did not break any software design rules, to comply with the stringent and impossible to meet! Performance system requirements**"*.

**Note:** Sarcasm is the art of lying.

Comment: Can you add a concrete answer to your answer? Is the sentence google translate gave me wrong or could I use this sentence eg in respect to colloquial language or maybe the patronizing "we" or the author's "we"?

Comment: @Matthias I was not happy with my original answer; neither was the OP who wished for concrete examples. So I deleted it, and gave him three good examples to consider. One positive; one negative; and one sarcastic. It is clear to me that the OP, would like to express a sarcastic statement. (Yes; I was drunk).